# Code so that when clicking on a button, an image is displayed in the same window

Tags: c#, maui

Good afternoon, I would like your help regarding this.

Code in C# Xamarin Net Maui, so that when clicking on a button, an image is displayed on the same screen.

I put images and example code

```
 <ScrollView>
        <VerticalStackLayout BackgroundColor="White">
            <Label Text="a" BackgroundColor="BurlyWood" ></Label>
            <Label Text="" TextColor="Black" ></Label>
            <Label Text="b" BackgroundColor="BurlyWood" ></Label>
            <Label Text="" TextColor="Black" ></Label>
            <Label Text="c" BackgroundColor="BurlyWood" ></Label>
            <Label Text="" TextColor="Black" ></Label>
            <Label Text="d " BackgroundColor="BurlyWood" ></Label>
            <Label Text="" TextColor="Black" ></Label>
            <Button x:Name="changeimage" Text="changeimage[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cK6um.png)" BackgroundColor="Aqua" Clicked="changeimage_Clicked" ></Button>
            <Image></Image>
            
        </VerticalStackLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

```
public partial class Pagina12 : ContentPage
{
    public Pagina12()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        
    }

    private void Cambiarimagen_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

[that when clicking on the button called "change image" an image is displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xk9PJ.png)

Thank you very much in advance

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first assign an `x:Name` to the `Image`

```
<Image x:Name="myImage />
```

then in your click handler

```
private void Cambiarimagen_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  myImage.Source = ImageSource.FromUri("http://blah.com");
}
```

see the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/image?view=net-maui-7.0) for different ways to load images

Comment: Thank you very much, I was looking for that code for many hours

Comment: If it is not much trouble, you will have a code to do the same thing you posted, but assuming that the button is on one page and the image on another page?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74513864/show-a-specific-image-in-a-window-page-contentpage-when-pressing-a-button-fro